# I'm working on a Cordova/Ionic app and fullscreen video play has stopped work in Chrome 73

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, video, fullscreen

Some users for my cordova app has reported issues playing videos in fullscreen after upgrading to Chrome 73. Anyone else having this issue?

We're currently using videojs version 4.

var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo"); 
elem.webkitRequestFullscreen;

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact warning shown in the dev tools console when you tap on the fullscreen button of the youtube player.

```
Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.
```

Don't exactly know if it is with youtube's js code or if any cordova permission needs to added for the new chrome update.